# Indenting within tables Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I've seen quite a few questions on this, but the answers don't seem to work for me. Within Word 2010, I want to increase (or decrease) the indent of a bulleted list.

`TAB` of course doesn't work (It goes to the next element), but `ALT+SHIFT+ ->` or `<-` seems to indent EVERYTHING in the table, which is not what I want to do. I've checked the settings and have not seen anything that would cause this action. Is there a setting or something I am missing?

**Edit:**
 
To be more clear, is there a way to do it without using the toolbar? I do this frequently while taking notes, and using the toolbar slows me down considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you assign keystrokes to the DecreaseIndent and IncreaseIndent commands.

To do that, go into File->Options->Customize Ribbon and click the Customize... button next to "Keyboard Shortcuts"

Then under Categories, select Home Tab.

Look for DecreaseIndent in the list on the right, click in the Press new shortcut key box, and press the key combination you want to use (e.g. alt-ctrl-shift-D does not seem to be assigned to anything. Ensure the keystroke is not assigned to anything else, then click Assign.

Repeat for IncreaseIndent, assigning (say) alt-ctrl-shift-I

Click Close, then cancel out of the Customize Ribbon dialog.

The problem seems to be that in a table, you normally use ctrl-Tab to do what Tab usually does outside the table. But in the special case where the insertion point is at the beginning of the paragraph, outside a table, Tab has the effect of "IncreaseIndent", whereas inside a table, ctrl-Tab does not, and just inserts a tab character as usual.

Comment: This is perfect. I can replace keyboard shortcuts I don't use with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list within a cell like this and you want to indent Item 3:
[image]

You can:

1. Place your cursor in Item 3 and click the **Increase Indent** or **Decrease Indent** buttons on the Home tab toolbar. [image]
2. Right click inside Item 3 and from the menu click **Increase Indent** or **Decrease Indent**.
3. Indent everything in that cell by setting its left margin. From the Table Tools **Layout** tab, click **Properties**, then switch to the **Cell** tab and click **Options**. Then uncheck the **Same as the whole table** checkbox and set your left margin as desired.

[image]